# How do I pay UK Air Passenger Duty (APD) on my flight to the UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, tickets, qatar-airways, taxes

I am Indian citizen travelling to UK for two weeks (Business Trip) with my wife (General Visitor). Our itinerary is India -> Doha -> London ->  Doha -> India.

I just read about UK [Air Passenger Duty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Passenger_Duty). I am not sure how I need to pay it and how much? Has this been included in my air tickets? I have already booked my tickets (Economy) with Qatar Airways.

Comment: It will be included in the ticket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are flying on a regular scheduled flight (clearly, you are), it is always included in the final price of the ticket. It is paid for by the operator (i.e. the airline). Source: https://www.gov.uk/pay-air-passenger-duty.